# Como retornar o índice de uma matriz e o seu valor em variáveis diferentes?

Tags: php, array, matriz

Tenho uma matriz da seguinte estrutura

```
Matriz[indice][valor]
```

Como eu retorno o índice em uma variável, e o valor em outra?

Exemplo esdrúxulo:

```
$indice = $matriz[indice]
```

E para o valor:

```
$valor = $matriz[indice][valor]
```

Exemplos de dados:

```
codigo = 116500, valor 10
codigo = 194800, valor 7
codigo = 245300, valor 40
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem duas funções chamadas:

```
$array_keys = array_keys($array); // retorna só as chaves
$array_values = array_values($array); // retorna só os valores
```

Exemplo:

```
$array = array('194800' => 'Forest', '194811' => 'River', '194812' => 'Sky');

$array_keys = array_keys($array);
$array_values = array_values($array);

print_r($array_keys);
print_r($array_values);
```

Você também pode juntar key + value:

```
$array = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

No loop:

```
// para mostrar os valores. por padrão já vai retornar só os valores,
// mas você pode aplicar a função array_values($array) se quiser.
foreach ($array as $result) {
    echo $result; 
    echo "<br>";
} 
// para mostrar as chaves
foreach (array_keys($array) as $result) {
    echo $result; 
    echo "<br>";
}
```

E para mostrar key e value no loop:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, e como eu faço para utilizar no laço? tipo $codigo = array_keys($array) e para o valor $valor = array_values($array);

Comment: @Adrianoecris, dei um update na resposta.

Comment: @Adrianoecris, http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: O link acima tem vários exemplos legais, dá uma olhada :)